# WordPress Sitemap Parse Error only on Production

Tags: wordpress, sitemap

Getting a Parse Error for a WordPress site for **sitemap.xml** on *Production* but the weird thing is I cannot replicate the issue on my ***local server***.

The error message is as follows:

```
This page contains the following errors: 
error on line 7 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document 
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

- I have tried 'Google XML Sitemaps' and 'Yoast SEO Plugin' with no change in the error.
- I am using the same source code.

What could be the reason behind this or the best approach I can take to debug this issue?

Comment: I have researched into the white space issue, but if it was the case then the problem should have been replicateable in the local server?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work! Just posting in the answer who face similar issues. When I viewed the page source, I observed that there are a couple of blank lines printed on top of my home page.

In order to debug, I deactivated each of the installed plugins and started activating one plugin at a time in order to narrow down to the plugin that was causing the error. The erroneous plugin was developed by me (my first) and noticed that there were blank spaces between ?> and the following

I also noticed that my local server had the 5 blank lines on top but it wasnt causing the parse error in the local dev when viewing the sitemap.xml file. Dont know what went in there but the above steps solved my problem.